# Parity Ethereum Node database size limit

Tags: ethereum

I'm running my own Parity Ethereum Node. The problem I'm facing is how to limit the size of database. Is it even possible?

The feature I'm looking for is to keep X last blocks and specify X size as a disk space.

Comment: StackOverflow is specifically about programming. Please ask this question on the [**Ethereum StackExchange**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) instead :)

Comment: Thank you. Should I remove this question?